# Increment list items by a certain value in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I'm trying to write a predicate that increments a list item by a certain value. I wrote this one but it's not giving me the correct result:

```
%--Increments every single list item by a certain Value.
incList([],[],_).
incList([X | List], [X2 | List2],Value) :-
    incList(List,List2),
    X2 is X + Value.
```

It only increments the first one. Any solutions on how to solve this without changing the structure of the predicate? Thank you.

Comment: You should take a look at maplist.

Comment: I don't want to use any of the built-in predicates. I'm avoiding that as far as I can. I want a solution that doesn't involve built-ins.

Comment: You have a typo on line 2 of second clause : incList(List, List2), it should be incList(List, List2, Value). Also, note that the order of parameters should be incList(List, Value, List2) because List and Value are "input" and List2 "output.

Comment: Yikes. How could I forget about that! Thanks! So what you are saying is to follow the convention of prolog? First the inputs and then outputs? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As joel76 mentioned I have a typo on line2 of second predicate. It should be `incList(List,List2,Value)` not `incList(List,List2)`.